# multiple definition of `method' in c

Tags: c, http, https, gcc, makefile

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial ([tutorial](https://gist.github.com/laobubu/d6d0e9beb934b60b2e552c2d03e1409e)) , exactamente como indica pero a pesar de copiarlo exactamente, el vscode me da error en `main.c`([image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]) y cuando ejecuto el coamndo `make` me da este error:

```
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -c -o httpd.o httpd.c
gcc -o server main.o httpd.o
/usr/bin/ld: httpd.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `method'; main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: httpd.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `uri'; main.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: httpd.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `qs'; main.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: httpd.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `prot'; main.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: httpd.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `payload'; main.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: httpd.o:(.bss+0x28): multiple definition of `payload_size'; main.o:(.bss+0x28): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:8: server] Error 1
```

Comment: O pones todo el código **Y EN FORMATO DE CÓDIGO (no imágenes)** o no podremos ofrecerte mucha ayuda

Comment: es mucho texto y no deja subirlo, todo mi codigo esta en el link de la publicacion @Londo

Comment: Es por eso que uno tiene que adjuntar un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_) y ser descriptivo para que no se muestre el mensaje de que tu pregunta parece ser mayormente código. ¿En qué consiste el programa? Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla.

Comment: solo quiero saber porque el codigo que estoy siguiendo no me funciona en mi computadora @padaleiana

Comment: Probablemente se deba a que las variables están declaradas en el .h de modo que ambos .c lo importan. Mueve las variables problemáticas (de la línea 10 a la 20 en el .h) al archivo `httpd.c`, justo antes de la primera función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus variables están siendo definidas por ambos `.c`, para evitar esto, en el header puedes agregar la declaración de la variable con `extern` para que tanto el `main.c` como `httpd.c` pueda acceder a ellas, pero únicamente sea `httpd.c` quien defina sus valores.

Agrega en el archivo  `httpd.h` las variables con extern, que hace que la variable se declare pero no se defina.

```
....

#include <stdio.h>

//Server control functions

void serve_forever(const char *PORT);

// Client request

extern char    *method,    // "GET" or "POST"
        *uri,       // "/index.html" things before '?'
        *qs,        // "a=1&b=2"     things after  '?'
        *prot;      // "HTTP/1.1"

extern char    *payload;     // for POST
extern int      payload_size;

char *request_header(const char* name);

....
```

En el archivo `httpd.c` agrega las definiciones reales de las variables:

```
...

#define CONNMAX 1000

char    *method,
        *uri,
        *qs,
        *prot;
char    *payload;
int      payload_size;

static int listenfd, clients[CONNMAX];

...
```